# GeoTagging Videos in Android

Tags: android

In Android it is possible to add `Geolocation` (lat and long) information to a picture. Under `Camera` settings, there is an option for it.

But for videos this is missing. Is there any other way to add `Geolocation` to video files?

Is it possible to use the `ExifInterface` class's [setAttribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use the `EXIF tags` for `Geotagging` pictures for sure.You can enable it via the `Camera` settings.

You can try reading the `video` files in and add the `tags` in your application.Android does not support `Geotagging` for videos. The video's `geo position` is stored, in the Android's `internal database`.

I haven't done it yet to be honest, but one way could be through using `web services`. You can create any webservice that will be consumed by the client.

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: I have tried, but currently there is no available Android class that can be used to read the Metadata of a video file, unlike picture files where it is possible to use EXIF tags.

Answer (score 0):

You add the information to the media database, rather than to the file itself. Here is an example of how to add data to videos: http://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/adding-video-metadata.html

Answer (score -3):

You can add the GPS coordinates to your videos with an Android app called MediaMapper Mobile from Red Hen Systems. They have a 14-day trial: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MediaMapper.Mobile&hl=en

Comment: Given the question, it would appear that @perumal316 is looking for a solution they can put in a project. An external application doesn't fill that requirement.